# Google Tag Manager Template Variable is not recognizing field values

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I was trying to implement a Variable template with a custom logic. For some odd reasons the Fields that were created ain't being recognised by data object in the code editor. When I try to access the fields using data.propertyName it logs as undefined.

Couldn't understand what's the issue.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Tried to access the fields from data object and expected the values given in the UI to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read from the datalayer variable. The datalayer is a property of your website, and your website is not present in the template preview, hence all values are undefined.

The confusion might come from the fact that there is an actual preview that tests your container configuration against your website. The preview in the screenshot is something different, that is the developer preview for custom templates.

If you wanted to test your custom template code as you develop it, [you would have to write test](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/templates/tests) and create a object with mock input data to run your code against.